# Proxy Wrap the iOS 14 Logger class

Tags: swift, logging, ios14

I have an app that is available on iOS 12. In the past I've used the excellent CocoaLumberjack, but I'd like to move to the native `Logger` class.

I'm happy for logs not to be collected for older iOS version, but I would like the app to run there.

Is there a good way to avoid `#available` calls everywhere? Generally I like `#available`, but for logging it's unwieldy

```
if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
     logger.info("Setting person from \(self.person, privacy: .public) to \(newValue, privacy: .public)")
}
```

If I wrap the `Logger` class, I can't get it to compile, because the logging system has compile time constraints:

```
import os

public class Logger {

    @available(iOS 14.0, *)
    static let logger = os.Logger(subsystem: "com.progress", category: "ProgressKit")

    public static func debug(_ input: String) {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            logger.debug(OSLogMessage(stringLiteral: input)) //  Fails: Argument must be a string interpolation
        } else {
            print(input)
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to use the new system do this without having `#available` statements everywhere??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's literally a special case in the compiler to ensure that `OSLogMessage` can only be constructed from a string literal.

https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/31109/files

That means there's no way to wrap it, and you're forced to either:

1. Expedite the obsolesce of old devices by dropping support for everything before Big Sur, and use the shiny new APIs directly, or
2. Don't use it, and use the os_log APIs, ugly as they may be.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not availability. The problem is that, as you’ve discovered, the argument to a Logger log command is not a String. It is a private class that is representable by a literal string. Thus you cannot pass a String into a wrapper and relay it to the Logger. You must call the Logger method directly with a literal string.

However, Logger is itself just an ingenious wrapper for `os_log` which does take a String. So you could use that instead. Or you could, as you suggest, just use availability and other backward compatibility techniques everywhere.

Comment: Thanks @matt! Do you know if os_log writes to disk in iOS 14? I guess from what you said it must do.

Comment: It does unless you tell it not to. Same as Logger. As I said, Logger is just a wrapper.

Comment: When I said "Do you know if os_log writes to disk in iOS 14?" what I should have said is "Is there an API to access the logs in iOS 14?" Although an API is available in macOS and was available in the iOS 14 betas it was pulled at the GM stage. Fingers crossed for iOS 15.

Comment: "Or you could, as you suggest, just use availability and other backward compatibility techniques everywhere." That's absolutely brutal. Logging code is all over the place. I'm really disappointed they didn't simply backport their wrapper, because it has a global effect on some of the most common code you write :/