# os_log wrapper crashed when using "%s"

Tags: ios, swift, oslog

I am trying to wrap `os_log` for logging in my iOS app like so:

```
import Foundation
import OSLog

enum LogCategory: String, CaseIterable {
    case viewCycle
    case tracking
    case api
}

struct Log {
    
    private static let logs = {
        return LogCategory.allCases
            .reduce(into: [LogCategory: OSLog]()) { dict, category in
                dict[category] = OSLog(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "BIMB", category: category.rawValue)
            }
    }()

    static func debug(category: LogCategory, message: StaticString, _ args: CVarArg...) {
        logImpl(category: category, message: message, type: .debug, args)
    }

    static func info(category: LogCategory, message: StaticString, _ args: CVarArg...) {
        logImpl(category: category, message: message, type: .info, args)
    }
    
    static func notice(category: LogCategory, message: StaticString, _ args: CVarArg...) {
        logImpl(category: category, message: message, type: .default, args)
    }
    
    static func warning(category: LogCategory, message: StaticString, _ args: CVarArg...) {
        logImpl(category: category, message: message, type: .default, args)
    }
    
    static func error(category: LogCategory, message: StaticString, _ args: CVarArg...) {
        logImpl(category: category, message: message, type: .error, args)
    }
    
    static func critical(category: LogCategory, message: StaticString, _ args: CVarArg...) {
        logImpl(category: category, message: message, type: .fault, args)
    }
    
    private static func logImpl(category: LogCategory, message: StaticString, type: OSLogType, _ args: CVarArg...) {
        guard let log = logs[category] else {
            return
        }
        os_log(message, log: log, type: type, args)
    }
}
```

The problem is if I did this:

```
Log.debug(category: .tracking, 
          message: "Device ID: %s.", 
          UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString ?? "unknown")
```

it always crashed with this error:

> 2023-12-13 12:33:35.173798+0700 bimb-authenticate-ios[62740:928633]
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Swift.__SwiftDeferredNSArray
> UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000dcbbc0'

But if I just do it with `os_log` like this:

```
os_log("Device ID: %s.",
       log: OSLog(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, category: "tracking"),
       type: .debug,
       UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString ?? "unknown")
```

it worked fine. Can you tell me what's wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: `%s` is for C-strings. Try using `%@`. Though I'm not sure why it would work when calling `os_log` directly.

Comment: Using %@ will display a pretty different value. With %s:

`Device ID: C0F906C8-CD73-44F6-86A1-A587248680D3.`

With %@:

`Device ID: (
    "C0F906C8-CD73-44F6-86A1-A587248680D3"
).`

Comment: Some useful info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65623070/7016052, https://stackoverflow.com/a/63036815/7016052.

Comment: @lazarevzubov Is `os_log` also using the `OSLogMessage` under the hood? I'm not using `Logger` since my app's minimal iOS version is iOS 11.

Comment: You should use %@. Why %@ gives brackets and spaces is another problem, we need some examples to reproduce it.

Comment: @Cy-4AH The examples are exactly above. They both use `UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString ?? "unknown"`

Comment: BTW, using `os_log("Device ID: %@.", ...` instead of `os_log("Device ID: %s.",...` returned the same thing, the ID is not inside brackets and carriage-return. It only happened in my wrapper class. But anyway, I will just use %@ for now. Brackets are minor issue.